# Elevens (11s) on Plimpton 322 (Babylonian Tablet)

Tags: math-history

Below is a modified photo of Plimpton 322 showing (what I believe to be) some hidden-in-plain-sight elevens (11s). [[source]](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Plimpton_322.jpg)

[image: Modified photo of Plimpton 322 showing hidden elevens (11s).]

If you text search the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plimpton_322) (about 12 pages), there is no reference to this (despite a lot of authors and hypotheses being presented).

I researched other sources, and I found one source that transcribes the elevens as ["ki"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086017300691), although I have yet to find a source that raises the possibility these are elevens.
I read elsewhere that eleven is usually written differently with [overlapping numerals](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/courses/m446-03/pl322/pl322.html).

With respect to circumstantial evidence of correctness, the translation of the column header seems to normally be "line". Modern English would typically interpret this as a line of text, but I think there's a possibility the word was used for geometric lines. You can even see a column separator that seems to group the two numbers together, indicating the possibility they are a fraction or an $(x, y)$ coordinate.

If you consider this fraction interpretation, the value becomes $\frac{11}{11}$ on row 11, which is notably alongside the data for a scaled-up $(3, 4, 5)$ triangle.

**Is there a discussion of Plimpton 322 that considers the possibility of these elevens (11s) being the denominators of fractions?** I have [written about it](https://gitlab.com/planetaria/onbifurcationsandbeauty/-/blob/main/OnBifurcationsAndBeauty.pdf?ref_type=heads), but I am curious if others have.

Comment: Did you know there’s a [history of science and math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I did not, thank you. I may cross-post later.

Comment: There are no denominators in Babylonian mathematics, and don't get me started on coordinates. This question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: There is a Sumerian tablet from ~3000BC (~1000 years prior) with both division and fractional values. https://youtu.be/MZVs6wF7nC4?si=fOI0r51951shh0Rm&t=610